# iPhone app error Expected identifier or '('

Tags: ios, objective-c

I have been looking around, haven't come up with much tho. Says there is an expected identifier error. This is the only error. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Im just getting a little confused, Im not sure if its because Ive been looking at is so long or not, it keeps giving me the parse error tho.

Here is my .h

```
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>
#import "AMRotaryProtocol.h"

@interface AMRotaryWheel : UIControl
-(void)drawWheel;
@property (weak) id <AMRotaryProtocol> delegate;
@property (nonatomic, strong) UIView *container;
@property int numberOfSections;

- (id) initWithFrame:(CGRect)frame andDelegate:(id)del withSections:(int)sectionsNumber;

@end
```

And .m

```
#import <QuartzCore/QuartzCore.h>
#import "AMRotaryWheel.h"

@interface AMRotaryWheel()

- (void) drawWheel
{
    // 1
    container = [[UIView alloc] initWithFrame:self.frame];
    // 2
    CGFloat angleSize = 2*M_PI/numberOfSections;
    // 3
    for (int i = 0; i < numberOfSections; i++) {
        // 4
        UILabel *im = [[UILabel alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, 100, 40)];
        im.backgroundColor = [UIColor redColor];
        im.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%i", i];
        im.layer.anchorPoint = CGPointMake(1.0f, 0.5f);
        // 5
        im.layer.position = CGPointMake(container.bounds.size.width/2.0,
                                        container.bounds.size.height/2.0);
        im.transform = CGAffineTransformMakeRotation(angleSize * i);
        im.tag = i;
        // 6
        [container addSubview:im];
    }
    // 7
    container.userInteractionEnabled = NO;
    [self addSubview:container];
}

@end

@implementation AMRotaryWheel

@synthesize delegate, container, numberOfSections;

- (id) initWithFrame:(CGRect)frame andDelegate:(id)del withSections:(int)sectionsNumber {
// 1 - Call super init
if ((self = [super initWithFrame:frame])) {
    // 2 - Set properties
    self.numberOfSections = sectionsNumber;
    self.delegate = del;
    // 3 - Draw wheel
    [self drawWheel];
}
return self;
}

- (void) drawWheel {

}

@end
```

Thank you for all the help.

Answer (score 3):

You have the method body in your `@interface` (`.h`) file, when you should only have your method prototype in the header file. The method body should be located in the corresponding `@implementation` (`.m`) file.

So in `AMRotaryWheel.h` you should have:

```
@interface AMRotaryWheel()
-(void) drawWheel;
@end
```

And in `AMRotaryWheel.m` you should have:

```
@implementation AMRotaryWheel
-(void) drawWheel {
  // method body here
}
@end
```

Comment: It the gives me "Expected ';' after method prototype. Thank you for the help tho!

Comment: Oh I see what's going on: your method body is in your `@interface` file (.h) instead of the `@implementation` file (.m). See edited answer.

Comment: well the only reason I put one there in the first place was that it gives me an error without one.

Comment: Without one what? A semicolon? See my edited answer if you haven't